# What is the direct sum of 1d domain walls in Toric code model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-computer, topological-field-theory, topological-order, category-theory

I have read this paper:"An invitation to topological orders and category theory" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05565v2). In page 93 and page 109, they show the result of fusion of simple 1d domain walls in Toric code model. The "sr" and "rr" domain wall can fusion out "2sr". I can follow the mathematical explanation，but I can't understand what "2sr" means.Does it means "the direct sum of two sr"? If so, what is the **direct sum** of 1d domain walls in Toric code model? How to understand it Physically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is hard to answer "What is the direct sum" without using category theory. Instead, I want to say something about "What does the direct sum of topological orders look like". The direct sum $\mathsf C$ of several topological orders $\mathsf C_1,\ldots,\mathsf C_k$ should have the following properties:

1. The direct sum $\mathsf C$ is an **unstable** topological order, in the sense that the ground state subspace of $\mathsf C$ is not one-dimensional. (In this answer, "ground states" always means "ground states on an open disk".)
2. Assume that $\mathsf C$ is realized by a lattice model and the Hamiltonian is denoted by $H$. Then for every $1 \leq i \leq k$, we can add a perturbation $\delta H_i$ in the Hamiltonian such that the perturbed Hamiltonian $H + \delta H_i$ realizes the topological order $\mathsf C_i$.
3. Let us denote the ground state subspace of $H$ by $V$. Then the ground state subspace of $H + \delta H_i$ can be identified with a subspace $V_i$ of $V$, and $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^k V_i$.

These are not the definition of a direct sum, but I believe these properties fully characterize a direct sum. Let me explain these properties in a simple example. Consider the 1d Ising chain:
$$
H = -\sum_i \sigma_z^i \sigma_z^{i+1} .
$$
(Remark: This Hamiltonian has a spin-flipping $\mathbb Z_2$-symmetry, but now we *forget* this symmetry. This means that the pertubations breaking the $\mathbb Z_2$ symmetry are allowed. Then this Hamiltonian realizes a 1d topological order.)

1. The ground state subspace is two-dimensional.
2. We can add a local perturbation $\delta H = \varepsilon \sigma_z^j$ to the Hamiltonian. If $\varepsilon > 0$, then $H+\delta H$ realizes the trivial 1d topological order because the unique ground state (spin-down state) is a product state. Simimlarly, if $\varepsilon < 0$, then $H+\delta H$ also realizes the trivial 1d topological order because the unique ground state (spin-up state) is a product state.
   (Remark: Note that this term $\delta H$ does not commute with the $\mathbb Z_2$-symmetry. So if we *impose* this symmetry, such a perturbation is not allowed, and the phase with $\mathbb Z_2$-symmetry is stable. See also Section 2.3.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.08835 for more discussions on this example with $\mathbb Z_2$-symmetry.)
3. The above two perturbed ground states span the ground state subspace of $H$.

So the Hamiltonian of the Ising chain realizes the direct sum of two copies of the trivial 1d topological order.

The direct sum of two "sr" domain walls in the toric code model also has these properties. Essentially these properties can be seen by studying the "narrow strip" in Figure 58, page 92 in our paper "An invitation to topological orders and category theory" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.05565v2). Note that the operator $X$ or $Y$ in Figure 58 can play the role of perturbations.

In addition, some related discussions can be found in Section 4.4.5 and Section 3.4.1 in our paper.

---

I will also give you a general construction of direct sums of 1d domain walls in the Levin-Wen model.

Recall that given a unitary fusion category $\mathcal C$, there is an associated Levin-Wen model (denoted by $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal C)$) and the particle-like topological defects form the unitary modular tensor category $\mathfrak Z_1(\mathcal C)$. Moreover, given two unitary fusion categories $\mathcal C,\mathcal D$ and a finite semisimple $(\mathcal C,\mathcal D)$-bimodule $\mathcal M$, there is an associated 1d domain wall (denoted by $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal M)$) between $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal C)$ and $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal D)$ and the topological defects form the unitary fusion category $\mathrm{Fun}_{\mathcal C|\mathcal D}(\mathcal M,\mathcal M)$. The detail of this construction can be found in Kitaev and Kong's work https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.5047.

Then you can check that the ground state subspace of $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal M)$ is one-dimensional if and only if the bimodule $\mathcal M$ is indecomposable. If, for example, $\mathcal M = \mathcal M_1 \oplus \mathcal M_2$ is decomposable, then we can apply a perturbation to obatin $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal M_1)$ or $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal M_1)$. In this case $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal M)$ should be the direct sum of $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal M_1)$ and $\mathsf{LW}(\mathcal M_2)$.

---

**Final remark**: Maybe a better way to understand direct sums is to use category theory and study the (higher) category of topological orders. We are also planning to add a subsection in later versions to discuss the category of topological orders.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $2\mathrm{sr}$ means $\mathrm{sr}\oplus\mathrm{sr}$.

The way to understand it physically is through correlation functions. Namely, given objects $a$ and $b$ (here, topological excitations, more precisely domain walls), there exists an object $a\oplus b$ such that
$$\left<\cdots\left(a\oplus b\right)\cdots\right>=\left<\cdots a \cdots\right>+\left<\cdots b \cdots\right>,$$
where the dots are arbitrary insertions.